# Algorithm for real matrix given the complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Given complex eigenvalues (occurring in conjugate pairs) how to get a single instance of a real matrix which has these eigenvalues. I know the matrix is not unique as eigenvectors are not fixed but in my case any real matrix will suffice.

Comment: If $\lambda_i\ne\lambda_j$, this is simple. For each eigenvalue $\lambda=a+bi$ you can take matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{pmatrix}$; whole matrix is block-diagonal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If eigenvalue is $a \pm bi$, the matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For more eigenvalue pairs, place $2 \times 2$ blocks like this one down the diagonal of your $2k \times 2k$ matrix.

Answer (score 4):

If the given eigenvalues are all distinct, then you can take the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_n)$, which has real coefficients because the roots occur in conjugate pairs.