# Calculate Real value Matrix from complex eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What I ask is exactly this
[Algorithm for real matrix given the complex eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345694/algorithm-for-real-matrix-given-the-complex-eigenvalues)

But in my case, Im looking for 4*4 matrix which gives 4 pairs of complex eigenvalues.

To be specific, I have following 4 eigenvalues.

Real     Img
-9.4661560         3.2088668
-9.4661560        -3.2088668
-0.13851462        0.66802061
-0.13851462       -0.66802061

Is there anyway to construct the 4*4 Real matrix with these values ?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like in the link you did.  The upper left hand 2 by 2 block will be the one for the first pair,  the lower right hand 2 by two block will be the one for the second pair, and the upper right and lower left will be all 0s.